# for loop try statements to ADD EXCEL DATA TO SD CARD using jxcelapi

Tags: java, android, excel, for-loop, try-catch

I'm stumped....:(
crated a simpler loop for testing but still only writes one cell...the first.
Can someone explain why in the loop it writes to log.d perfectly and addcell does not.....

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String Fnamexls="testfile"  + ".xls";
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Lottery");
    directory.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(directory, Fnamexls);

    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook;
    try {

        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
```

shoul the loop be insithe the try func.

```
        for (int a =0;a<10;a++){

            test = a;
            label4 = new Label(0,test,String.valueOf(test));

            try {
                sheet.addCell(label4);
                Log.d("log1","a: "+a+" test:  "+test);

            } catch (RowsExceededException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            workbook.write();
        }
        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //createExcel(excelSheet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm stumped....:(
crated a simpler loop for testing but still only writes one cell...the first.
Can someone explain why in the llop it writes to log.d perfectly and addcell does not.....